# Spring String & Map Injection

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection

I've a simple question.(odd scenario for me)

I've this bean below.

```
@Configuration
public class ConfigurationBean {

@Bean
public Config getConfig() {
    return ConfigFactory.load();
}

@Bean
public Map<String, String> tableMap(Config config) {
    return config.getObject("tables").unwrapped().entrySet().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, e -> e.getValue().toString()));
}

@Bean
public String url(Config config) {
    return config.getString("url");
}
}
```

And my service class;

```
@Component
public class TableService  {
private final Map<String, String> tableMap;
private final String url;
private Connection connection;
private final TableToJsonConverter tableToJsonConverter;

@Autowired
public TableService(TableToJsonConverter tableToJsonConverter,
                    String url,
                    Map<String, String> tableMap) {
    this.url = url;
    this.tableMap = tableMap;
    this.tableToJsonConverter = tableToJsonConverter;
}
```

So the scenario is,
`url` bean returns value `www.google.com`.
`tableMap` bean returns `newGame:new_game_table,oldGame:old_game_table`

Now what I am expecting to inject map to map, string to string in the constructor of `TableService`. But what really happens is, `url` is inserted correctly however the map is injected as `url:www.google.com`

[image: TableMapContent]

[image: See here]

I am a bit puzzled, could you please let me know what's happening here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please try: Add `@Qualifier("tableMap")` to constructor argument.

Comment: @xerx593 that doesnt help. However if i name the bean then use that as a qualifier it works. But I don't want to use qualifiers for something simple like this. I want to learn the reasoning behind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is expected behavior. Spring supports taking collection types to pass in multiple beans. So `List<MyPojo>` will inject a list of all the MyPojo beans. What is happening in your case, is Spring is injecting the bean name / string value since that is a `Map<String, String>`.

You shouldn't have to name beans though, the default bean name is the method name. The qualifier is a valid workaround in this case.

Comment: That's bit weird... but thanks. I thought it'd just inject the url value to the strings that's named "url" so that the bean name matches. So in my case is the qualifier only way to do it for the strings that's named url to be injected `google.com` and maps that's named tableMap to be injected?

Comment: @Bleach its only "weird" because you want to make a string and/or a map of strings a bean which is in of itself, "weird". That's not a common practice and Spring skews toward common practice. Sounds like those two properties are "related" so you wouldn't pass them around individually as beans, you'd define a class that holds them i.e. `MyConfigurationProperties` and make that the bean. Then you wouldn't have to use @Qualifier, etc. and things would work as you are expecting.

Comment: I think what you suggest makes sense. Thanks.